# Best performance addition modulo 2^32 implemetation

Tags: c, performance, modulo, addition

I'm working on SHA-256 implementation and I got to the point where addition modulo `2^32` of unsigned numbers is needed.

My first thought was to use an overflow behavior:

```
uint32_t a = ...;
uint32_t b = ...;
uint32_t c = a + b;
```

But I have two concerns:

- Is overflow always defined behavior and if I can rely that it will work as
  modulo addition `sizeof(_operand_)` if both operands and result
  variable are of the same type?
- How to get rid of compiler warnings
  about possible overflow, the proper way?

My second thought was to implement it using variable of longer type:

```
uint32_t a = ...;
uint32_t b = ...;
uint64_t a_64 = a;
uint64_t b_64 = b;
uint64_t c_64 = a_64 + b_64;
uint32_t c = uint32_t(c_64 & 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

But this solution needs several additional variables, their initialization and additional bitwise AND operation.

Which of these implementations (if any) is correct in terms of `C` programming principles and performance? If none of them, what is the proper implementation?

Comment: unsigned integer overflow is defined behaviour in c, so you can rely on that behaviour with uint32_t

Comment: Unsigned arithmetic is **defined** to wrap in C 2018 6.2.5 9, so there is no overflow.

Comment: A compiler might warn about a narrowing conversion (e.g. 64-bits to 32-bits) but never about an unsigned overflow.

Comment: I am curious why the compiler issues a warning. Even in an obvious case where I set `a` and `b` to high values, there is no warning.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not getting warnings, I was sure that compiler would generate them. I'm sorry, the explanation in post was not clear enough.

Comment: @Klepak Please describe precisely what problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uint32_t` is a modulo-2^32 type. It is not only a type with range at least up to 2^32-1, but maybe more per hardware requirements; that would be `uint32least_t`.

So, addition on `uint32_t` is always modulo addition, and it is not suitable for operations where a concept of overflow is desired. The best solution is simply `a+b`.